# Why won't workmanager run my job if my app is closed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I want to do some periodic work even when my app is closed. 
According to the `WorkManager` docs:
 *WorkManager is intended for work that is deferrable—that is, not required to run immediately—and required to run reliably even if the app exits or the device restarts.*
For troubleshooting purposes, I have made a function that calls my server every hour and tells it to send me an email.
The work in question:

```
class TestMailWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters)
    : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        //Cloud.sendTestMail() opens a SSL connection to my server 
        //and sends some data which triggers my server to send an email:
        return if (Cloud.sendTestMail()) Result.success() else Result.retry()
    }
}
```

This makes my server send me a test email.
 It is called from

```
fun scheduleTestMails(){
// TEST_EMAIL is a const val String to be used as a tag.
    val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build()
    val task = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<TestMailWorker>(Duration.ofHours(1)).apply {
        setConstraints(constraints)
        addTag(TEST_EMAIL)
    }.build()
    with (WorkManager.getInstance(App.instance)){
        enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TEST_EMAIL, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, task)
    }
}
```

And this schedule function is called form my main `App` class:

```
class App : Application(){
//(...)
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
//(...)
        MyWorkersHub.scheduleTestMails()
    }
}
```

When my app is started for the first time, I get an email. If I close the app (or restart my phone, etc), I not longer get emails.

Looking through `adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler` (as suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging), thank you [pfmaggi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118862/pfmaggi)) I see that the job, indeed, stays in even after killing the app. However, even with all signs on go, it doesn't excute:

```
  JOB #u0a407/1959: 2c4f52a nl.mydomain.myapp/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
    u0a407 tag=*job*/nl.mydomain.myapp/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
    Source: uid=u0a407 user=0 pkg=nl.mydomain.myapp
    JobInfo:
      Service: nl.mydomain.myapp/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
      Requires: charging=true batteryNotLow=false deviceIdle=false
      Extras: mParcelledData.dataSize=180
      Network type: NetworkRequest [ NONE id=0, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&VALIDATED Uid: 10407] ]
      Minimum latency: +15m59s958ms
      Backoff: policy=1 initial=+30s0ms
      Has early constraint
    Required constraints: CHARGING TIMING_DELAY CONNECTIVITY [0x90000001]
    Satisfied constraints: CHARGING BATTERY_NOT_LOW TIMING_DELAY CONNECTIVITY DEVICE_NOT_DOZING BACKGROUND_NOT_RESTRICTED WITHIN_QUOTA [0x93400003]
    Unsatisfied constraints:
    Tracking: BATTERY CONNECTIVITY TIME QUOTA
    Implicit constraints:
      readyNotDozing: true
      readyNotRestrictedInBg: true
    Network: 143
    Standby bucket: ACTIVE
    Enqueue time: -33m32s112ms
    Run time: earliest=-17m32s165ms, latest=none, original latest=none
    Last run heartbeat: 0
    Ready: false (job=true user=true !pending=true !active=true !backingup=true comp=true)
```

(I made some changes on restrictions, in case you are wondering why this doesn't match the code above, but the problem stays the same)

There is probably something pretty basic that I am missing, but I just don't see it.
**My question:** What do I need to change to make sure my Periodic Work is actually executed periodically?

Comment: On which device are you testing this and how?

Launching your application from Android Studio is not exactly as launching it from the launcher. Also some devices are force stopping an application when you swipe it out from the recent apps list. Take a look at how to debug WorkManager: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging

Comment: Keep also in mind that ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE is going to cancel the current Worker if it is currently running (the Coroutine Scope is going cancelled). If you just need to be sure this is running, please consider using ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP.

Also, which WorkManager version are you using?

Comment: -using Workmanager 2.4.0
-Switched to KEEP, was on replace for some earlier debugging
-Installed from Android Studio, launching from launcher (I think, will make sure)
-Running it on a OnePlus 7 Pro (physical device)
-That link is a big help, will take some time to sift through the data that generated :)

Comment: Take a look to the Don't Kill my app website, regarding OnePlus restrictions: https://dontkillmyapp.com/oneplus

You may try to play with those settings to see if they make a difference.

Comment: Also https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter may help, gut I've not tested it.

Comment: thanks, it was indeed my phone being overzealous when it comes to stopping background work!

Comment: Thanks for confirming. You should accept your answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

The code I already used works just fine. The problem was with my OnePlus phone stopping background work from being done. [this](https://dontkillmyapp.com/oneplus) lead me to the solution (settings - battery - battery optimization - don't optimize my app. We'll see about fixing this later, if ever. Seems to be pretty specific for oneplus.)